# How join two dataframes with multiple overlap in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

Hi I have a dataset of multiple households where all people within households have been matched between two datasources. The dataframe therefore consists of a 'household' col, and two person cols (one for each datasource). However some people (like Jonathan or Peter below) where not able to be matched and so have a blank second person column.

| Household | Person_source_A | Person_source_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Oliver | Oliver |
| 1 | Jonathan |  |
| 1 | Amy | Amy |
| 2 | David | Dave |
| 2 | Mary | Mary |
| 3 | Lizzie | Elizabeth |
| 3 | Peter |  |

As the dataframe is gigantic, my aim is to take a sample of the unmatched individuals, and then output a df that has all people within households where only sampled unmatched people exist. Ie say my random sample includes Oliver but not Peter, then I would only household 1 in the output.

My issue is I've filtered to take the sample and now am stuck making progress. Some combination of join, agg/groupBy... will work but I'm struggling. I add a flag to the sampled unmatched names to identify them which i think is helpful...

My code:

```
# filter to unmatched people
df_unmatched = df.filter(col('per_A').isNotNull()) & col('per_B').isNull())

# take random sample of 10%
df_unmatched_sample = df_unmatched.sample(0.1)

# add flag of sampled unmatched persons
df_unmatched_sample = df_unmatched.withColumn('sample_flag', lit('1'))
```

Comment: what if your sample includes both `Oliver` and `Peter`? which household would you pick then?

Comment: Sorry I probably havent explained it clearly. In that case, I'd want the output to just show households 1 and 3 as they'd be the households that included the sampled unmatched people Oliver, Jonathan and Peter. (I should say that unmatches result in an empty second person column, never the first)

Comment: I think you better update your question with example samples for each cases

Comment: There's no variations. I just want to reduce my dataframe to only show the full households of households where an unmatched person exists that has been selected by a random sample out of all unmatched people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it pertains to your intent:

> I just want to reduce my dataframe to only show the full households of
> households where an unmatched person exists that has been selected by
> a random sample out of all unmatched people

Using your existing approach you could use a join on the `Household` of the sample records

```py
# filter to unmatched people
df_unmatched = df.filter(col('per_A').isNotNull()) & col('per_B').isNull())

# take random sample of 10%
df_unmatched_sample = df_unmatched.sample(0.1).select("Household").distinct()

desired_df = df.join(df_unmatched_sample,["Household"],"inner")
```

#### Edit 1

In response to op's comment:

> Is there a slightly different way that keeps a flag to identify the
> sampled unmatched person (as there are some households with more than
> one unmatched person)?

A left join on your existing dataset after adding the flag column to your sample may help you to achieve this eg:

```py
# filter to unmatched people
df_unmatched = df.filter(col('per_A').isNotNull()) & col('per_B').isNull())

# take random sample of 10%
df_unmatched_sample = df_unmatched.sample(0.1).withColumn('sample_flag', lit('1'))

desired_df = (
    df.alias("dfo").join(
        df_unmatched_sample.alias("dfu"),
        [
            col("dfo.Household")==col("dfu.Household") , 
            col("dfo.per_A")==col("dfu.per_A"),
            col("dfo.per_B").isNull()
        ],
        "left"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks this definitely answers the question. Is there a slightly different way that keeps a flag to identify the sampled unmatched person (as there are some households with more than one unmatched person)?

Comment: @Olivander you may have a look at the updated answer

Comment: Much appreciated!